# How do I reset a view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to reset a tic-tac-toe game after somebody wins.  I have an alert controller set up when somebody wins.  I was it so that when a specific button is pressed it will reset the view controller to the original state so that the players can play another game.  Here is the code I have for one specific win:

```
if (positionOne == 1000001 && positionTwo == 1000002 && positionThree == 1000003) 
{            
 var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Player One Wins!!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        var okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Aww man, that sucks.  I demand a rematch!", style: .destructive) 
 { (action) in

            self.topLeftLabel.text = "-"
            self.topMiddleLabel.text = "-"
            self.topRightLabel.text = "-"

            self.middleLeftLabel.text = "-"
            self.middleMiddleLabel.text = "-"
            self.middleRightLabel.text = "-"

            self.bottomLeftLabel.text = "-"
            self.bottomMiddleLabel.text = "-"
            self.bottomRightLabel.text = "-"



            var positionOne = 1
            var positionTwo = 2
            var positionThree = 3
            var positionFour = 4
            var positionFive = 5
            var positionSix = 6
            var positionSeven = 7
            var positionEight = 8
            var positionNine = 9


        }
        var deathButton = UIAlertAction(title: "I'd like to see the board", style: .default)
        alert.addAction(deathButton)
        alert.addAction(okButton)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I was it so that when the "Death Button" is pressed the game is reset.  however when I do this is clears the board and everything but whenever I click anything the dialog just immediately pops back up.  How do I fix this?[image: This is the alert that shows up when you win. The rematch button should reset it but it doesn't work.]

Comment: do you have a variable which indicates if a player has won?

Comment: What function is this code located in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to programmatically reset all your properties. so you should create a function to reset the game and call in when the user taps on the `okButton` that you have created.

your reset function should reset the turns and delete the images of the previous moves from the board .

Comment: how would I reset the game with that function?  Can you upload some code to show me?